# single table reccuring relatives

Tags: mysql, sql, self-join

Can't name it less confusing, sorry...
Imagine the DB table with 3 columns:

- **object_id** - some entity,
- **relation_key** - some property of the object,
- **bundle_id** - we must generalize different objects with this id.

Table has *unique* key for [**object_id**, **relation_key**]: 
single object can't have duplicated **relation_key**, 
but different objects can have equal **relation_key**

Some oxygen understanding with the picture:
[image]

Plenty objects can have deep relations by relation_key, all this objects will be related with **bundle_id**

How can I update bundle_id column with correct values using just single query?
I can write procedure but this way is unsuitable for me.

---

I look for statement like:
"UPDATE example [join example ON ...] SET bundle_id = ... WHERE ..."

there is "before" schema for mysql:

```
CREATE TABLE `example` (
  `bundle_id` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `object_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `relation_key` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`object_id`,`relation_key`) 
);

INSERT INTO `example`(`object_id`, `relation_key`) 
VALUES (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 6), (2, 7), (2, 8), (3, 4), 
(3, 9), (3, 10), (4, 11), (4, 12), (4, 13), (5, 14), (5, 15), (5, 16), (6, 17), (6, 11), (6, 18);
```

---

Here is the example "before": [fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/254fa/1)   (sqlfiddle stuck for this moment)

And "after" will look like like if you do the queries :

```
UPDATE `example` SET `bundle_id` = 1 WHERE `object_id` IN (1, 2, 3);
UPDATE `example` SET `bundle_id` = 2 WHERE `object_id` IN (4, 6);
UPDATE `example` SET `bundle_id` = 3 WHERE `object_id` IN (5);

object1 related to object2 by key=6, 
object3 related TO object1 by key=4, 
so ... objs 1, 2, 3 are related together. 
here must be first bundle_id=1. 
there is no other keys linking another objects to 1, 2, 3

object_id=4 related to object_id=6 by key=11
so ... obj [4, 6] are related together. 
here must be second bundle_id=2, 
there is no other keys linking another objects to 4, 6  

object_id=5 has no relations to other objects
all object's key belong to itself. 
here must be second bundle_id=3, 
there is no other keys linking another objects to 5
```

Comment: Please explain what logic should be used to "update bundle_id column with correct values". What value is correct? What value is not correct? Edit the question and add some representative sample data and how the final result should look like. Both tables should be posted as text, not as image.   Also, add the tag with the DBMS that you use and its version.

Comment: Yes, the question is much better now, but I don't know how to do it in MySQL. As far as I know it doesn't support recursive queries.